# How to change a color of table's caption when knitting?

Tags: r, r-markdown, flextable, readable

I was wondering whether there is an easy way to change the colour of the `flextable` table caption without the use of CSS?

````
---
title: "Test"
output:
  html_document:
    highlight: tango
    theme: readable
---

```{r}
library(flextable)
library(tidyr)
```

```{r}
flextable(iris[1:6,]) %>%  set_caption(caption = "Iris Dataset")  
```
````

Here is my output: I would like to have a table title in black
[image]

Comment: I know I can add teh following to markdown: </style>
<style>
caption {
      color: black;
    }
</style>. But I know it is not a good practice to do so

Comment: looks like [set_flextable_defaults(extra_css = "caption { color: #000; }")](https://github.com/davidgohel/flextable/blob/9947fbef2623b6491fea544cd66eb06eea5caf2a/R/defaults.R#L23) is the way, but it doesn't change anything

Comment: thanks, @rawr, I have made a bug report for this issue.  hope it will be an easy fix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

so I asked the `flextable` developer team and they suggest using:

````
```{css}
caption {
  color:red;
}
```
````

which is not really a solution as I cant for example set a different header for different tables, and it requires the use of CSS ( which is a bad practice to add it into the rmd document)